# Fetch/get cart ID

Tags: shopify

I am developing a Shopify App in order to track the abandoned and recover customer.

Is there any way by which we can fetch or get the cart id? or is there any way by which we can track the recovered customer after abandon checkout in shopify?

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify API allows you to gather abandoned checkouts at the Order level.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders

No need to fetch cart ID.